# Import website XML-feed to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xsd, xml-parsing

Hope you all are doing well.

I need to import an XML-feed from a website to my SQL Server database. I don't know much about XML.

The feed structure is an bit complex. Here is the sample of that file:

```
<line_feed>
<FeedTime>1279519582927</FeedTime>
<lastContest>4103839</lastContest>
<lastGame>58629754</lastGame>
<events>
<event>
    <event_datetimeGMT>2010-07-19 21:30</event_datetimeGMT>
    <gamenumber>174087393</gamenumber>
    <sporttype>Tennis</sporttype>
    <league>abc</league>
    <participants>
        <participant>
            <participant_name>R. Ram</participant_name>
            <contestantnum>4303</contestantnum>
            <rotnum>4303</rotnum>
            <visiting_home_draw>Visiting</visiting_home_draw>
        </participant>
        <participant>
            <participant_name>K. Beck</participant_name>
            <contestantnum>4304</contestantnum>
            <rotnum>4304</rotnum>
            <visiting_home_draw>Home</visiting_home_draw>
        </participant>
    </participants>
    <periods>
        <period>
            <period_number>0</period_number>
            <period_description>Game</period_description>
            <periodcutoff_datetimeGMT>2010-07-19 21:30</periodcutoff_datetimeGMT>
            <period_status>I</period_status>
            <period_update>open</period_update>
            <spread_maximum>250</spread_maximum>
            <moneyline_maximum>1500</moneyline_maximum>
            <total_maximum>250</total_maximum>
            <moneyline>
                <moneyline_visiting>135</moneyline_visiting>
                <moneyline_home>-146</moneyline_home>
            </moneyline>
        </period>
        <period>
            <period_number>0</period_number>
            <period_description>Game</period_description>
            <periodcutoff_datetimeGMT>2010-07-19 21:30</periodcutoff_datetimeGMT>
            <period_status>I</period_status>
            <period_update>open</period_update>
            <spread_maximum>250</spread_maximum>
            <moneyline_maximum>250</moneyline_maximum>
            <total_maximum>250</total_maximum>
            <spread>
                <spread_visiting>2</spread_visiting>
                <spread_adjust_visiting>101</spread_adjust_visiting>
                <spread_home>-2</spread_home>
                <spread_adjust_home>-118</spread_adjust_home>
            </spread>
            <total>
                <total_points>22.5</total_points>
                <over_adjust>-108</over_adjust>
                <under_adjust>-108</under_adjust>
            </total>
        </period>
        <period>
            <period_number>1</period_number>
            <period_description>1st Set</period_description>
            <periodcutoff_datetimeGMT>2010-07-19 21:30</periodcutoff_datetimeGMT>
            <period_status>I</period_status>
            <period_update>open</period_update>
            <spread_maximum>5000</spread_maximum>
            <moneyline_maximum>250</moneyline_maximum>
            <total_maximum>5000</total_maximum>
            <moneyline>
                <moneyline_visiting>114</moneyline_visiting>
                <moneyline_home>-133</moneyline_home>
            </moneyline>
        </period>
    </periods>
</event>
</events>
</line_feed>
```

Can you please help me out, how can I approach to load the data from that feed to SQL Server.

Please also ask me if any other details needed to understand this scenario. Awaiting your kind response.

Thank You,
Prashant

Comment: There's a tag mismatch in `<FeedTime>1279519582927</PinnacleFeedTime>`; is that a typo, or is your real feed malformed?

Comment: Thank you for spotting that typo, I have corrected it.

Comment: The data appears fairly straightforwad, mostly just nested records. So... when you say "load the data from that feed to SQL server" - do you want to take the data, parse it into data (records) to use in your database? And if so are you expecting to do this in SQL Server itself or using an external application?

Comment: What we want is, import data from XMLfeed to SQL Server tables, I believe we need more than one table to populate the data. We don't use any external application, wants to straight parse into SQL Server. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is wel-formed, you can store it in an `xml` type variable.  Then you can use XPath to read fields from it:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml = '
<line_feed>
<PinnacleFeedTime>1279519582927</PinnacleFeedTime>
...
'

select @xml.value('(line_feed/events/event/sporttype)[1]', 'VARCHAR(8000)')
```

This would print `Tennis`.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on what you want to extract from your feed....

I'm assuming here that you have your XML stored in a SQL Server variable like this:

```
DECLARE @input XML
```

This query here will enumerate over all `<participants>` nodes and extract all information about a single participant - you could use this to insert those participants into a table:

```
SELECT
    Feed.Participant.value('(participant_name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS ParticipantName,
    Feed.Participant.value('(contestantnum)[1]', 'int') AS ContestantNum,
    Feed.Participant.value('(rotnum)[1]', 'int') AS RotNum,
    Feed.Participant.value('(visiting_home_draw)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS VisitingHome
FROM
    @input.nodes('/line_feed/events/event/participants/participant') AS Feed(Participant)
```

Output:

```
ParticipantName ContestantNum   RotNum  VisitingHome
R. Ram                  4303        4303     Visiting
K. Beck                 4304        4304     Home
```

This second query enumerates the `<period>` nodes in your feed - again, it extracts some information, which you could use to store in a database table:

```
SELECT
    Feed.Period.value('(period_number)[1]', 'int') AS PeriodNumber,
    Feed.Period.value('(period_description)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS PeriodDescription,
    Feed.Period.value('(period_status)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Status,
    Feed.Period.value('(period_update)[1]', 'varchar(50)') AS Update,
    Feed.Period.value('(moneyline_maximum)[1]', 'decimal(18,4)') AS MoneylineMaximum
FROM
    @input.nodes('/line_feed/events/event/periods/period') AS Feed(Period)
```

Output:

```
PeriodNumber   PeriodDescription   Status  Update  MoneylineMaximum
    0             Game                I     open      1500.0000
    0             Game                I     open       250.0000
    1             1st Set             I     open       250.0000
```