# WhiteHouse.gov Data - XML > DB

Tags: xml, database, visual-studio, ssis, dtd

I'm doing some research on the US Gov't budget, and would like to be able to pull the data for each individual agency from their Appendix and load it in to a database. The Appendix is located here http://www.whitehouse.gov/omb/budget/Appendix/

I tried reading in the XML files through a Visual Studio SSIS, but it gives me an error of there not being a DTD or schema to do so. There is also the .rar file of all agencies and their budgets - this includes some DTD files, among others.

Sorry, I'm quite new to this and am not sure where to start. As a work around, I was thinking of converting the XML to CSV then importing that file in to SSIS, as I have done that before.

Any and all suggestions and help are well appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Further up on the same page there are links to what (at least appear/claim to be) the accompanying DTD files.

Comment: What do I do with those accompanying files? Visual Studio only gives me an option for XSD files.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sorry I didn't clarify. What do I do with these files in order to upload them in to the database?

Comment: This question might give you some leads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350514/load-xml-by-ssis-dtd-is-prohibited-in-this-xml-document-error